# How do i create line breaks in ruby?

Tags: ruby

How would i put line breaks in between lines like this:

```
print "Hi"
print "Hi"
```

Because it would just output this:

```
HiHi
```

Comment: `\r\n` should probably do the trick.

Comment: use `puts` instead of `print`

Comment: Do you mean a space or a line break?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Use [`puts`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/IO.html#method-i-puts) since it will automatically add a newline for you:

```
puts "Hi"
puts "Hi"
```

If you want to make an explicit newline character then you'll need to know what kind of system(s) on which your program will run:

```
print "Hi\n"   # For UNIX-like systems including Mac OS X.
print "Hi\r\n" # For Windows.
```

Answer (score 1):

Use line break character:

```
print "Hi\n"
print "Hi"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a space by adding a string with only a space in it between the 2 other strings. For example:

```
print "Hi" + " " + "Hi"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could avoid the two print statements and instead only use one line.

```
print "Hi\r\nHi"
```

Or if you want to use two lines then

```
print "Hi\r\n"

print "Hi"
```

Answer (score 0):

puts "\n" works also on Win/Ruby ruby 2.4.2p198
and even "\n"*4 for multiplication of new rows (by 4)