# How to get to newline in Ruby output?

Tags: ruby

Below is my code snippet

```
pr_num = 311
"Merging #{pr_num}: cool "
```

I get the output as:

```
Merging 311: cool
```

But I want:

```
Merging 311:
cool
```

How do I get the output in the desired format? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do i create line breaks in ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14696944/how-do-i-create-line-breaks-in-ruby)

Answer (score 4):

Use `\n`:

```
"Merging #{pr_num}:\ncool "
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a newline, type a newline:

```
pr_num = 311
"Merging #{pr_num}:
cool "
```